# How to clear Django's cached query after prefetch_related

Tags: django-orm

I'm rendering a list of items with their related reviews.  I used prefetch_related so it won't issue a new query for each item's reviews.

```
items = Item.objects.all().prefetch_related('reviews')
```

Later, I add a review and try to re-calculate the average:

```
item = items[0]
Review.objects.create(item=item, score=5)

# recalculate average
reviews = item.reviews.all()
...
```

Oh no!  This list of reviews doesn't include the one I just created.  How can I clear this cache so the query can be performed fresh?  Or should I be creating the review differently?

Comment: try: `item.reviews.nocache().all()`

Comment: Where are you getting this from?  I don't see such a thing in the documentation or the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prefetch_related(None)`

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct answer as he want to do it after querying.

The correct way is using :

```
_remove_prefetched_objects
```

In this case :

```
item.reviews._remove_prefetched_objects()
```

Comment: This is what worked for me, not the one marked as the answer.